# Azure IoT Hub: "Signing certificate info did not match chain elements"

Tags: java, azure, azure-iot-hub, client-certificates, azure-iot-hub-device-management

I was following this tutorial (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-dps/tutorial-group-enrollments) where the goal is to create a group enrollment in Azure Provisioning Service and connect a simulated device to it. After creating the group enrollment and the certificates, I'm stuck on a error related to the signing certificates not matching. This happens on step 7 of the "Simulate the device" part of the tutorial.

Image related to the error:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q5x8g.jpg

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Have you seen this other question with same error? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50817794/auto-provisioning-device-under-an-enrolment-group-does-not-work-java-sdk

Answer (score 2):

The problem arises when you create certificate with Windows Powershell.
Easy way would be use Git bash and generate the certificate with bash commands on Windows platform.

You can do two things here:

1. Select CA certificate in the DPS enrollment list and use Root CA certificate that is uploaded in the "certificates" tab of DPS, instead of uploading intermediate 1 certificate that is signed by Root CA.
   Add the device certificate keys in the simulated application and run it. It worked in my case. Although its not a right way to do this if there is multitenancy situation and you want to use intermediate certificate.
2. The powershell command file generates certificate chain something like this RootCA->intermediate 1->intermediate 2->intermediate 3

so intermediate certificate 3 is signed by intermediate 2 which is signed by intermediate 1 and then it is signed by Root

Also all the device certificates are signed by root CA (Root CA-> leaf certificate) hence you are getting error "the intermedite certificate does not match the signing certificate".
You can edit the file, go to function New-CACertsDevice() in the param give $signingCertSubject as the name of intermediate certificate 1 which will be "Azure IoT CA TestOnly Intermediate 1 CA"